# Can I use a usb hub to transfer images from my phone into another device?

Tags: file-transfer, phone, usb-hub

I looked at a number of USB hubs (not powered ones) and I see it written that the hub should not be used to charge a wireless device. But can I connect a phone to tranfer files? Is there a risk to the devices if I do that?

Comment: The hub is not the issue. The issue is whether the phone will allow itself to be seen as media device (like a hard drive) on another system. And even then if the phone OS itself will allow access to the files on the phone to be copied at all.

Comment: A USB hub is irrelevant.  What is this *"another device"*? You would need to use the proper USB cable to ensure that the phone's USB port is in the proper mode for this *"another device"*, i.e. device mode to connect to a PC, or host mode for a storage device.  IOW you might need a plain USB cable or an [OTG adapter or OTG cable](https://www.samsung.com/nz/support/mobile-devices/what-is-an-otg-cable-and-what-is-it-used-for/).   BTW all USB hubs need/use power, either from an external power supply or else from the host over the USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

No hub is required, as long as both the PC and the phone are
connected to your local network and can see each other.

The simplest method is to
install an SSH server on your phone, for example SSHDroid on Android.
Once launched, you could access the phone's files from Windows.

A great (free) Windows utility is
[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php).

Some small knowledge (or experimenting) will be required via WinSCP
to find the phone folder containing the files to transfer.

Comment: *"No hub is required ..."* -- Ambiguous wording.  At first I assumed you meant that the hub is not necessary for just a single USB device, and just plug that device into the host port.  Instead it seems like you're suggesting to not use USB at all.

Comment: @sawdust: I mean to say that a local network connection is enough, as when PC and phone are both connected to the same router.